# Will I be charged "bounced check" fee if I already closed my account?

Tags: check

#### Situation:

- I have closed the account.
- I have the cheque book.
- I want to use
  these pieces of paper for an art project.
- Someone may inevitably try
  cashing in the cheque.
- **Will some fee be charged, will I land in jail?**

#### Related:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-sufficient_funds
- http://www.ckfraud.org/faq.html#3
- [What is the difference between a bad/bounced check and insufficient funds?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/60936/what-is-the-difference-between-a-bad-bounced-check-and-insufficient-funds)

#### Assumption:

I'll make it clear that cheque is a piece of paper, and I will not even sign a cheque...

Comment: Any reason why you want to use it as art paper. Most countries advice that checks be kept in safe place. Returned to bank or destroyed on account closure.

Comment: The reason why I would like to use check as an art paper is simple - it's unique in my part of the world - to the point where people are framing it and hanging on the wall - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwtRriViR24&index=15&list=PL1rxP_DEyCW87KGqT6zZ9Oo4KJRG6oBmx

Answer (score 4):

An unsigned check should not be a risk unless someone forges your signature -- which could be a hassle but is probably not a serious risk if the account is already closed. If you are worried, "sign" the check as *Void*, which explicitly marks it as invalid.

Personally, I would shred the leftover checks. The risk is minimal, but why force yourself to worry? If you must use checks for your art project, you can have fake checks printed up, eliminating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**No fees** will be charged and **no jail** for you. Why? Because the account is closed.

It is an art project, fine.  But, if you fear the impossible, just to be on the safe side fill out every check with technical errors: date too old or invalid, value in pennies or in millions, invalid beneficiairy and the like. Even if stolen, no bank will accept a check with errors. The check will never bounce back because it will not be a valid check.